Antivirus catches “CVE-2024-4577” vulnerability even though there is no php in my code
I have a web project with Svelte and the antivirus application throws such an error even though there is no php related code block in it. Under node_modules, there is only one php file in the “flatted” library related to php and I couldn't find anything related to it.
These are the libraries I used for development
{
    "@fontsource/fira-mono": "^4.5.10",
    "@neoconfetti/svelte": "^1.0.0",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.28.1",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "prettier": "^2.8.0",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.8.1",
    "svelte": "^3.54.0",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^5.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "vite": "^4.0.0",
    "vitest": "^0.25.3"
}

A friend working before me for IIS stands up a windows service and redirects ports with url rewrite, their codes are below
import { handler } from './build/handler.js';
import express from 'express';
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/healthcheck', (req, res) => {
res.end('ok');
});
app.use(handler);

app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('listening on port 3000');
});

service.js
import nodeWindow  from 'node-windows'
var Service = nodeWindow.Service;
var svc = new Service({
 // 
});
svc.on('install',function(){
 svc.start();
});

svc.install();

thank you in advance for the help

"such an error" - what does that even mean?

in the screenshot sent to us by the organization, the antivirus application writes “vulnerability exploit attempt” and the detection name is “CVE-2024-4577” @NicoHaase

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, including any error message you're facing in text form

Is it possible that you have PHP installed even though you are not using it? The vulnerability seems to affect PHP directly so it would make sense that your scanner flags it as an issue.

CVE-2024-4577 is not a vulnerability in userland code, it's a vulnerability in the engine itself, in particular some CGI SAPI on Windows. As said, you may have PHP installed side by side with Node. For example, you may have installed XAMPP to use MySQL or phpMyAdmin.
